# Kept getting Target Unreachable, identifier resolved to null in JSF web app

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2

i have a simple problem here
i am making a simple jsf web app that can upload file
but i kept getting

```
Target Unreachable, identifier 'upload' resolved to null
```

here's my upload class

```
package SimpleLogin;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.apache.myfaces.custom.fileupload.UploadedFile;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class upload {

private UploadedFile uploadedFile;

public void submit() throws IOException {
    String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(uploadedFile.getName());
    String contentType = uploadedFile.getContentType();
    byte[] bytes = uploadedFile.getBytes();

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
        new FacesMessage(String.format("File '%s' of type '%s' successfully uploaded!", fileName, contentType)));
}

public UploadedFile getUploadedFile() {
    return uploadedFile;
}

public void setUploadedFile(UploadedFile uploadedFile) {
    this.uploadedFile = uploadedFile;
}
```

}

and my index page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
  >
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/jsfcrud.css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
     <ui:composition template="./template.xhtml">

        <ui:define name="body">
                <h:form>
                <h:commandLink action="/contacts/List" value="Show All Contacts Items"/>
            </h:form>

            <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <t:inputFileUpload value="#{upload.uploadedFile}" />
            <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{upload.submit}" />
            <h:messages />
            </h:form>

        </ui:define>
     </ui:composition>
```

oh yeah, here's my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee /web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
<filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Sorry for the long delay
here my face config.xml

```
<faces-config version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns /javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">

<managed-bean>  
    <managed-bean-name>user</managed-bean-name>  
    <managed-bean-class>SimpleLogin.simpleLogin</managed-bean-class>  
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>  
</managed-bean>    

<managed-bean>
     <managed-bean-name>bean</managed-bean-name>
     <managed-bean-class>SimpleLogin.Upload</managed-bean-class>
     <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope></managed-bean>

<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>
        #{simpleLogin.CheckValidUser}
        </from-action>
        <from-outcome>fail</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/resultforfail.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>
        #{simpleLogin.CheckValidUser}
        </from-action>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
<application>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>/Bundle</base-name>
        <var>bundle</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>
```

and my template

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
     <h:head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
         <title><ui:insert name="title">Default Title</ui:insert></title>
 <h:outputStylesheet name="css/jsfcrud.css"/>
 <h:outputStylesheet name="css/cssLayout.css"/>
 <h:outputStylesheet name="css/default.css"/>
    </h:head>

<h:body>
    <div id="top">
        <ui:insert name="top">Ini Header</ui:insert>
    </div>

    <h1>
        <ui:insert name="title"></ui:insert>
    </h1>
    <p>
        <ui:insert name="body"></ui:insert>
    </p>

    <div id="bottom">
        <ui:insert name="bottom">Ini Footer</ui:insert>
    </div>

</h:body>
```

what is the problem ? do i not clearly state the upload class ?
Any help is good :)

Comment: I think you should try changing your ManagedBean's class name to `Upload`.

Comment: @Mr.J4mes i already do that, still not working

Comment: Did you make any update to your `web.xml` file?

Comment: One more thing is can you try add this constructor `public Upload() {}` to your Upload class?

Comment: i put the web xml on the post

Comment: How about the other thing? Did it help?

Comment: i also add the constructor
but still no good

Comment: Explicitly adding a default constructor is nonsense. As to your concrete problem, show the `template.xhtml` and `faces-config.xml`. The problem is in either of them.

Comment: @BalusC i put those files in the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have overridden the `@ManagedBean` by a `<managed-bean>` declaration on the `faces-config.xml`, however that `<managed-bean>` declaration has a different managed bean name, namely `bean` instead of `upload`.

You have basically 3 options:

1. Use `#{bean}` instead of `#{upload}` in your view.
2. Rename the `<managed-bean-name>` in `faces-config.xml` from `bean` to `upload` so that you can use `#{upload}` in your view.
3. Get rid of `<managed-bean>` altogether so that the `@ManagedBean` will be used. The managed bean name defaults to the bean class name with 1st char lowercased, thus `#{upload}` should work.

For the remaining, you are not consistent with [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367). Please work on that as well. Package names should be all lowercase and class names should be CamelCase and start with uppercase.

Comment: wow, it worked !! Thanks a lot
but i wonder, where the uploaded file go ?
I search the project folder but i dont find it..

Comment: You're welcome. As to the uploaded file content, just get it by `UploadedFile#getInputStream()` and write it to an arbitrary `OutputStream` the usual way. You should not care about where it's initially been stored. It's a temporary location on disk or in memory anyway.

Comment: are there any simple way beside that ?
like using tomahawk or else ?
i'm getting confused about using inputstream ?
it would very helpfulfor me if you like to explain it:)

Comment: Uh, just use `IOUtils.copy(uploadedFile.getInputStream(), someOutputStream);`. If you stucks, just ask a new question. This is offtopic.

Comment: phew, i don't understand
but thanks for the answer. It really helpful,maybe in future i will ask many question about java, i am currently working on a project here. 
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Just press `Ask Question` button if you have a question.